# Pandas insert or update?

Tags: python, pandas

If I'm doing df.update() on a frame for which the key doesn't exist, what's the cleanest way I can add it?

Something like:

```
try:
  df.update(new_data)
except:
  df.insert(new_data)
```

Comment: why not just test `if key in df.columns:`? Also is the new_data the same size? i.e. same number of rows? why not just overwrite if so or create new column with the new data?

Comment: [Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) is the preferred python way

Comment: Thanks for your question. If you're satisfied with the answer - it would be great if you'll mark any answer as correct. If you still need some answer improvements - feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use:

```
df['new_column_name'] = new data
```

It'll update your column, and create new if there's no such column.

In case if you still want to process cases where there's no column, you are trying to update - you may use:

```
if new_column_name in df.columns:
    do_something()
else:
    do_something_else()
```

At last - if you need to insert a new column to some particular place in your DataFrame, you may use something like this:

```
if new_column_name in df.columns:
     df['new_column_name'] = new data
else:
     df.insert(place_you_need_column_in, 'new_column_name', new data)
```

If you want to follow EAFP coding style, you may use some trick - trying to insert at first(it'll return an error if column already exists):

```
try:  # It'll be executed only if you don't already have a column with 'new_column_name' in your df
    df.insert(place_you_need_column_in, 'new_column_name', new data)
except:
    df['new_column_name'] = new data
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what the real use case here, but firstly you can test if the key exists already by calling `in` on the columns:

```
In [61]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('abc'))
df

Out[61]:
          a         b         c
0 -0.968358  0.666118  0.758028
1 -0.805671 -0.994780  0.624423
2  0.449329  0.768457 -0.311637
3 -0.793448  1.258319 -0.924384
4  1.698867 -0.624939 -0.167027

In [62]:
'd' in df.columns

Out[62]:
False
```

Besides if the column doesn't exist then you can just add it whether it's a scalar value or the array is the same length:

```
In [63]:
df['d'] = 10
df

Out[63]:
          a         b         c   d
0 -0.968358  0.666118  0.758028  10
1 -0.805671 -0.994780  0.624423  10
2  0.449329  0.768457 -0.311637  10
3 -0.793448  1.258319 -0.924384  10
4  1.698867 -0.624939 -0.167027  10
```